# How to consume a Spring boot Rest Web Service?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

Hello I am new with creating a spring boot rest web service.
 My goal is to have a UI to pass parameters and retrieve some values.

In soap UI I can enter WSDL url. Then manually type the required fields in, and I would receive an out put.

Right now I want to want to use rest and retrieve the same values.
How would I be able to send a request call? If I am doing rest what is the equivalent to wsdl? and what URI do I use?

**Edit**

I have found an Mountpoint, and wadl for rest. What do I have to do with these?

Comment: There are some browser's plugin to consume Rest WS. Take a look to [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/restclient/) for firefox or [RESTful](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-web-service-client/ecjfcmddigpdlehfhdnnnhfgihkmejin?hl=fr) WS for chrome.

Comment: So you want to consume a rest web service or you want to build one in spring?

Comment: I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UP-v1dTOT9g. But I want to retrieve my own data , not the web service I created following that video. @viruskimera

Comment: You mean that you want to get data on the client side from a rest service?

Comment: @MoatezBouhdid Yes. How would I be able to do so? I have to pass some params to retrieve the data. So If I send some type of params. I should get a response of some data.

Comment: Firstly most REST services use JSON and validating it was challenging so I use JSON LINT http://jsonlint.com/ for validation. So once you have a rest service you can use a number of browser plugins e.g Chrome: Postman. However, I have found that Swagger is a fantastic way to map your entire API check out this demo http://petstore.swagger.io/#!/pet.

Comment: @DanHargis I know in soap I can provide a wsdl and a endpoint url. Then I can send a request with params and retrieve values based on the request. Can I replicate that with what you said above? I don't think I need to produce a web service. I just need to pass params and obtain values back from the server.

Comment: @MoatezBouhdid Its kind of confusing with REST but since you only have HTTP verbs (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, …) on a resource you just really need to understand what the payload is going to be.. So really what you want is the payload expected and the end point. However,  WSDL 2.0 can "Describe REST Web services". Here is a link:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restwsdl/
Hope that helps I had the same questions coming from a SOAP background.

Comment: @DanHargis So ultimately what URL/URI and resources do I need to start? eg; for SOAP, I needed a endpoint url. and a wsdl file that I generated from the wsdl url.

Comment: @MoatezBouhdid Since I use Swagger instead of WSDL a couple other programmers on my team said to check out WADL.. WADL works much like WSDL. WADL files can be created from Netbeans, Eclipse, and InteliJ. I just broke out NetBeans and created a WADL file based on some REST services that I created in Spring( Very simple). I followed this video to make sure it worked https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7kt9Bhhq8g

Comment: @MoatezBouhdid  I still think that Swagger is the way to go http://swagger.io/ . After looking into it further Swagger Codegen is specifically designed for this very problem.